# Collision destroy a cube when player collides

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

Unity- I have a mesh named and tagged as player I want that when it touches a Cube it should get destroyed C# script I need ....ty

Comment: Check out [OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) and [Destroy](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html).